# Can someone help me optimize this for speed?

Tags: python, string, optimization, replace

Herewith the code for optimization:

```
import random

rules = {
    'X': {
        1: 'FXFF+',
        2: '+XXF]',
    }
}

L_string = 'FX'

def next_char(c):
    isrule = rules.get(c, c)
    if not isrule == c:
        _, choice = random.choice(list(rules.get(c).items()))
        return choice
    else:
        return isrule

for _ in range(6):
    L_string = ''.join([next_char(c) for c in L_string])
```

Whats happening here is a recursive replacement of characters in a string. So step by step:

1. Start with 'FX'
2. Go through string and replace each 'X' with a random rule i.e. 'FXFF+' or '+XXF]'. That is for **each** 'X' a rule is randomized. It's not a random rule for each run through the string.
3. Repeat this for 5 times

In the end the result is a longer string made up of the starting 'F' and the rules 'FXFF+', '+XXF]' in some random combination. The table illustrates:

```
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| ITERATIONS |       STRING       | CHOSEN RULE VECTOR |
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|          1 | FFXFF+             | [rule 1]           |
|          2 | FF+XXF]FF+         | [rule 2]           |
|          3 | FF+FXFF++XXF]F]FF+ | [rule 1, rule 2]   |
|          4 | ...                | ...                |
|          5 | ...                | ...                |
+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

I've read that re.sub is the fastest for replacing strings but the problem is the randomization at each character. Re.sub won't work for that.

Thanks all!

Comment: How long is that string? Is this really such a performance bottleneck?

Comment: what's the performance issues? what's the actual amount of rules and `L_string` length that cause a performance hit?

Comment: Just small improvement: `choice = random.choice(list(rules.get(c).values()))`

Comment: Imagine the rules are 'XXXXF' and 'XXXXF'. The length of the final string then becomes 5462 and this must be done for a couple hundred thousand of these guys. Also, the rule length may increase later to 10 characters long then my PC crashes because the string is too large for memory

Comment: @OlvinRoght Sorry, for this example I omitted the dictionary 'key' value but I actually need it in my complete code. So its `key, choice = random.choice(list(rules.get(c).items()))`

Comment: I am using multiprocessing so that speeds things up a lot but RAM becomes an issue with larger strings

Comment: why accumulating a huge string in a single variable? does it need to be eventually stored/written somewhere?

Comment: @AlbinPaul I'll keep that in mind if I move to longer rule strings. For now I think file writing will be inefficient

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes, it turns into a whole other thing later

Comment: Thank you all, it seems @altunyurt's method is the fastest (by 9 nano seconds :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New method with recursion, approx ~1.6x faster and another method, approx ~3.312x faster on my PC

```
import re
from random import random, choice
from timeit import timeit
from math import floor

# --- ORIGINAL ---
rules = {
    'X': {
        1: 'FXFF+',
        2: '+XXF]',
    }
}

def next_char(c):
    isrule = rules.get(c, c)
    if not isrule == c:
        _, _choice = choice(list(rules.get(c).items()))
        return _choice
    else:
        return isrule

# --- ORIGINAL END ---

def next_char2(c):
    if c not in rules:
        return c

    d = rules[c]
    r = floor(random() * len(d))  # was int(...) before
    # Rules start with key 1.
    # Random brings a float between 0 and 1, therefore you need [r + 1] as key
    return d[r + 1]

choices=['FXFF+', '+XXF]']
def next_substring(s, n):
    if s == '' or n == 0:
        return s

    first_char = s[:1]
    rest = s[1:]

    if first_char == 'X':
        first_char = choice(choices)

    if len(first_char) == 1:
        return first_char + (next_substring(rest, n) if 'X' in rest else rest)
    else:
        return (next_substring(first_char, n-1) if 'X' in first_char else first_char) + (next_substring(rest, n) if 'X' in rest else rest)

format_rules = {
    'X': lambda: choice(["{F}{X}{F}{F}+", "+{X}{X}{F}]"]),
    'F': lambda: 'F',
    'J': lambda: 'J',
}

def format_based():
    def get_callbacks():
        while True:
            yield {k: v() for k, v in format_rules.items()}
    callbacks = get_callbacks()
    L_string = "{F}{X}"
    for _ in range(6):
        L_string = L_string.format(**next(callbacks))
    return re.sub(r'{|}', '', L_string)


def method1():
    s = 0
    for i in range(100_000):
        L_string = 'FX'
        for _ in range(6):
            L_string = ''.join([next_char(c) for c in L_string])
        s += len(L_string)
    return s

def method1b():
    s = 0
    for i in range(100_000):
        L_string = 'FX'
        for _ in range(6):
            L_string = ''.join([next_char2(c) for c in L_string])
        s += len(L_string)
    return s


def method2():
    s = 0
    for i in range(100_000):
        L_string = 'FX'
        L_string = ''.join(next_substring(c, 6) if c=='X' else c for c in L_string)
        s += len(L_string)
    return s

def method3():
    s = 0
    for i in range(100_000):
        L_string = format_based()
        s += len(L_string)
    return s

rules2 = [
    ('FXFF+', '+XXF]')      # X=0
]

def new_method2(s='FX'):
    final = [s]
    s = ''
    for _ in range(6):
        for c in final[-1]:
            if c == 'X':
                s += rules2[0][floor(random() * len(rules2[0]))]    # rules2[0] because X=0
            else:
                s += c
        final.append(s)
        s = ''
    return final[-1]

def method4():
    s = 0
    for i in range(100_000):
        L_string = new_method2('FX')
        s += len(L_string)
    return s

print('Average length of result string (100_000 runs):')
print('{: <20}{: >20}'.format('Original:', method1() / 100_000))
print('{: <20}{: >20}'.format('New method:', method2() / 100_000 ))
print('{: <20}{: >20}'.format('@hilberts method:', method3() / 100_000 ))
print('{: <20}{: >20}'.format('new_method2 method:', method4() / 100_000 ))
print('{: <20}{: >20}'.format('altunyurt method:', method1b() / 100_000 ))

print('{: <20}{: >20}'.format('Timing original:', timeit(lambda: method1(), number=1)))
print('{: <20}{: >20}'.format('Timing new method:', timeit(lambda: method2(), number=1)))
print('{: <20}{: >20}'.format('Timing @hilberts method:', timeit(lambda: method3(), number=1)))
print('{: <20}{: >20}'.format('new_method2 method:', timeit(lambda: method4(), number=1)))
print('{: <20}{: >20}'.format('altunyurt method:', timeit(lambda: method1b(), number=1)))
```

The results:

```
Average length of result string (100_000 runs):
Original:                       85.17692
New method:                     85.29112
@hilberts method:               85.20096
new_method2 method:             84.88892
altunyurt method:               85.07668
Timing original:       4.563865200005239
Timing new method:    2.6940059370026574
Timing @hilberts method:  1.9866539289942011
new_method2 method:   1.3680451929976698
altunyurt method:     1.7981422250013566
```

EDIT: Added @hilberts method

EDIT2: Added another new method, ~3.32x faster than original

EDIT3: Added @altunyurt method

Comment: And the winner is @hilberts method!!

Comment: @ZackJoubert Yep, it's quite original too :)

Comment: @ZackJoubert Added new method, ~3.32x faster than your original. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Would you mind timing all the other algorithms against @altunyurt's answer?

Comment: @ZackJoubert added. So far mine is fastest.

Comment: Great! I'll leave the question unanswered for a couple of days to see if there are any more contributions then I will choose the fastest method as the answer

Answer (score 2):

A simple ~4x speed up on the function that consumes most of the run time.

```py
from random import random
from math import floor

def next_char2(c):
    if c not in rules:
        return c 

    d = rules[c]
    r = floor(random() * len(d))  # was int(...) before 
    # Rules start with key 1. 
    # Random brings a float between 0 and 1, therefore you need [r + 1] as key 
    return d[r + 1]


In [6]: %timeit next_char("X")
3.42 µs ± 32.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit next_char2("X")
814 ns ± 12.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

Edit: Changing the int with math.floor gives a little boost

In [10]: %timeit next_char2("X")                                                                
740 ns ± 8.57 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

There might be a lot room for optimization. Maybe a memoization somewhere might give a huge boost in general for the whole code.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming characters '{' and '}' do not occur in your patters, you could do some trickery with the template language and strip braces afterwards. This is 2.5x faster on my machine:

```
def format_based():
    rules = {
        'X': lambda: random.choice(["{F}{X}{F}{F}+", "+{X}{X}{F}{J}]"]),
        'F': lambda: 'F',
        'J': lambda: 'J',
    }
    def get_callbacks():
        while True:
            yield {k: v() for k, v in rules.items()}
    callbacks = get_callbacks()
    L_string = "{F}{X}"
    for _ in range(5):
        L_string = L_string.format(**next(callbacks))
    return re.sub('{|}', '', L_string)
```

Comment: Still the fastest method even with this improvement https://stackoverflow.com/a/57348467/7167076

Comment: This is fastest, I've edited my answer and added it to my mini-benchmark

Comment: Not really even sure how it works but that's my problem :)

Comment: I'm sure that randomization and callbacks can be optimized further, e.g. as in @altunyurt's answer.

Comment: Oh but alas, now my rules have to be curly braced

Comment: Feel free to unaccept the answer, I am sure that we have not reached a conclusion yet.

Comment: Also, how to keep the possibility of recording the rule index i.e. rule 1 was chosen then rule 1 again then rule 2 etc.

Comment: Hang on, it still seems like @altunyurt's answer is the fastest

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `re.sub` with replacement value as a function that generates random rules as per your case. You could write the string to a file in disk and 
[`set buffering`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127889/python-read-stream) when reading the file and then write to another file the substituted values and then rename the file and delete the old one. Hope this helps :).

```
import re
import random
rules = {
    'X': ['FXFF+','+XXF]'],
    "Y" : ['A','B']
}

L_string = 'FX'

def next_char(c):
    return random.choice(rules[c.group()])

for _ in range(6):
    L_string = re.sub('|'.join(rules.keys()),next_char,L_string)
    print(L_string)
```

OUTPUT

```
FFXFF+
FFFXFF+FF+
FFF+XXF]FF+FF+
FFF++XXF]+XXF]F]FF+FF+
FFF+++XXF]FXFF+F]+FXFF+FXFF+F]F]FF+FF+
FFF++++XXF]FXFF+F]FFXFF+FF+F]+F+XXF]FF+F+XXF]FF+F]F]FF+FF+
```

**EDITED**

I have edited to make it fast and to produce the last string with a recursive call. Pardon me for using global variables :P.

```
import re
import random
rules = {
    'X': ['XX','XY'],
    'Y' : ['A', 'B']
}

L_string = 'FXY'
depth = 6
result = ''
index = 0 

def go(d,currentstring) :
    global result,depth
    if (d < depth):
        for c in currentstring:
            if c in rules:
                go(d + 1,random.choice(rules[c])) 
            else:
                result += c
    else:
        result += currentstring
go(0,L_string)
print(result)
```

Comment: Just to check, this randomizes a rule for each 'X' right?

Comment: This wont work if theres more than one replacing character right say 'X' and 'Y' with two rules each?

Comment: Yes it randomises for each `X` and for the second comment wait one sec Ill modify and update it to work

Comment: @ZackJoubert I have modified it,  it was my fault I thought you only had the X as the rule, I have generalised it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do a speed check quickly

Comment: Nope, seems the old methods is still faster. Rules = 'XXXXF' & 'XXXXF'. Old method = 0.019074s. This method = 50.213758s

Comment: @ZackJoubert I understand, one more question. Do you require the last string only or all the strings in the loop ?

Comment: Last string only. Did run the timings without the `print(L_string)`

Comment: @ZackJoubert can you check my edited version of the answer one more thing the rules must have single digit characters this case.

Comment: Nope, this is still fastest https://stackoverflow.com/a/57348476/7167076

Answer (score 0):

This generates the output without substitutions:

```
import random

result = []
write = result.append

def X(level):
    if level == 0:
        write('X')
        return
    if random.randint(0,1):
        # X -> FXFF+
        write('F')
        X(level-1)
        write('FF+')
    else:
        # X -> +XXF]
        write('+')
        X(level-1)
        X(level-1)
        write('F]')

def start():
    write('F')
    X(5)  # 5 = recursion depth

start()
print(''.join(result))
```

Comment: Wow! More than 50% faster. However, what if you have more than one variable say 'X' and 'Y'?

Comment: You can add another function for 'Y'. `X` may call `Y(level-1)` and vice versa. The speed is achieved by rewriting the rules from data structures to program instructions, so it is little bit less flexible.