# How to read the file of huge size(gb) in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I repeatedly hear this question. I don't have any hands-on these scenarios.
As I can learn and get many approaches/ideas to do the same, so would like to understand

```
1) What would be the best approach ?
2) What would be the efficient way to do this ?
```

According to me, I would approach to break down the huge file size to smaller files (I mean, `Batches`).
Let's say, I have 2 files with data to be manipulated (Each file `sorted` and `un-sorted` order).
Definitely, reading such huge file results to memory error (won't be able to load file depending upon RAM).

```
1) How can it be achieved through Python ?
2) Best time saving and efficient method ?
3) Can Python-Pandas achieve this ? If yes, how ?
```

Very curious to hear from you.Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python read stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127889/python-read-stream)

Comment: @MilanVelebit : Will https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127889/python-read-stream solve this problem ?

Comment: The typical advice is to use [`Dask`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/) or if you want, just [process the files in chunks with `pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html?highlight=chunksize#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk).