# Python - Reading a large audio file to a stream?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pydub

### The Question

I want to load an audio file of any type (mp3, m4a, flac, etc) and write it to an output stream.

I tried using `pydub`, but it loads the entire file at once which takes forever and runs out of memory easily.
I also tried using `python-vlc`, but it's been unreliable and too much of a black box.

So, how can I open large audio files chunk-by-chunk for streaming?

### Edit #1

I found *half* of a solution [here](https://superkogito.github.io/blog/ffmpegpipe.html#digaud), but I'll need to do more research for the other half.

**TL;DR:** Use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) and [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) to convert the file to `wav` data, and pipe that data into `np.frombuffer`. The problem is, the subprocess still has to finish before `frombuffer` is used.

...unless it's possible to have the pipe written to on 1 thread while np reads it from another thread, which I haven't tested yet. For now, this problem is **not solved**.

Comment: take a look at opening up a file to stream  https://stackoverflow.com/a/26128216/147175

Answer (score 0):

I think the python package https://github.com/irmen/pyminiaudio can be of helpful. You can stream an audio file like this

```
import miniaudio


audio_path = "my_audio_file.mp3"
target_sampling_rate = 44100  #the input audio will be resampled a this sampling rate
n_channels = 1  #either 1 or 2
waveform_duration = 30 #in seconds
offset = 15 #this means that we read only in the interval [15s, duration of file]

waveform_generator = miniaudio.stream_file(
     filename = audio_path,
     sample_rate = target_sampling_rate,
     seek_frame = int(offset * target_sampling_rate),
     frames_to_read = int(waveform_duration * target_sampling_rate),
     output_format = miniaudio.SampleFormat.FLOAT32,
     nchannels = n_channels)


for waveform in waveform_generator:
    #do something with the waveform....
```

I know for sure that this works on mp3, ogg, wav, flac but for some reason it does not on mp4/acc and I am actually looking for a way to read mp4/acc